# How to encode attachments for use via Trello web API

Tags: trello

The `file` parameter [documentation](https://trello.com/docs/api/card/index.html#post-1-cards-card-id-or-shortlink-attachments) for the `POST /1/cards/[card id or shortlink]/attachments` API call does not specify how the file should be encoded.  For "Valid Values" it simply says "A file".  I was wondering if anyone has a working example of how to get files into Trello cards using the API.

Comment: Trello uses that API to attach files, so you should be able to use it as an example.  (i.e. you can look at the Network tab in Chrome after attaching a file)

Comment: API questions are off-topic here, it *might* work on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) but be sure to show prior work in the form of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add an attachment using the `multipart/form-data` content type:

```
<form action="https://api.trello.com/1/cards/REPLACE_WITH_CARD_ID/attachments"
      method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="hidden" name="key" value="REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_KEY" />
   <input type="hidden" name="token" value="REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_WRITE_TOKEN" />
   <input type="file" name="file">
   <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

(You don't necessarily have to be `POST`ing from a webpage, but that's an easy example)

Comment: If I'm not using HTML forms can I just set the value of the file parameter in the post to a Base64 encoded file? Or will I somehow need to convert that into multipart/form-data?  Sorry if I'm being stupid.

Comment: The library we're using to handle forms doesn't yet support base64

Comment: @JackJones Did you manage to upload a file the way you wanted? Were you trying to actually accept a file upload from the user, or some pure-javascript trick? I'm looking for solutions for uploading strings as files for my [Trello Attachment Editor](https://websitesfortrello.github.io/attachments/), since to this day it is using the browser `File` API, which is only supported in Chrome and Firefox.